# Link SVG animation model with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, synchronization, smil

Is it possible to link SVG animation model with Javascript custom processing? Specifically, SVG animation has an internal clock which synchronizes all animation elements. Besides, there are other ways  to do animation with Javascript (e.g. with setTimeout, setInternval). I wonder if there are any ways to link SVG animation with Javascript code, so that we can use Javascript to do some custom animation not supported by SVG SMIL but still able to be harmonized with SVG animation model.

Appreciate any ideas.

Cheers,
Bruce

Comment: You question is became very actual now since Chrome has plans to remove SMIL supprot:
> CONSOLE WARNING: SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. 
> Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead
We got basic SMIL actions https://wiki.mozilla.org/SMIL:SMIL_Model and it should be possible to create corssbrowser js-used events
Here my similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965580/deprecated-smil-svg-animation-replace-to-css-or-web-animations-effects-hover-c

Answer (score -2):

You can use anime.js, vivus.js or GSAP library.

Comment: Sorry if I did add some 401 characters on my answer review. Could someone explain what 401 characters mean because I really don't know?