# Workaround to Chrome warning for embedded YouTube videos, "SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed."

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, svg, youtube, warnings

It appears that embedding a YouTube video,

```
<iframe id="yt" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kBh1A3D2XP8"
        width="250" height="140" frameborder="0"
        webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

produces the following warning in Chrome (47.0.2526.106 m):

[image]

(Determined by setting a breakpoint and stepping out of the function a few times.)

The warning, transcribed:

> SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.

Is there something I can do to get rid of this warning?

I saw [Deprecated SMIL SVG animation replaced with CSS or Web animations effects (hover, click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965580/deprecated-smil-svg-animation-replaced-with-css-or-web-animations-effects-hover) but my question is about Javascript I can't control (`base.js` comes from YouTube). Also found [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/3lguuo) with no solutions.

Comment: 1 - set filters in your console. 2 - Ask Google to work a little bit on SMIL and to stop with this wrong message (SMIL is only deprecated by Chrome, not by the specs). + that's kind of ironic they do use it themselves in YT :-)