# SVG animate from circle to line

Tags: css, animation, svg

I want to shape a circle to a line (path).
Is this possible?

Maybe it's the way I Google that might be the problem.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 95.28 95.28">
  <title>circle</title>
  <circle cx="47.64" cy="47.64" r="47.14" fill="none" stroke="#1d1d1b" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
```

The best way (for me) would be if the top and bottom come together.
But I'm more interested on how to do this! I couldn't find anything on how to shape the svg element

--------- SMALL UPDATE ----------
Just found [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-animatetransform-for-inline-svg-animation--cms-22296). It might help me get a direction.

--------- SMALL UPDATE ----------
So I tried to do this without JQuery but I think it won't work.
The reason for thsi is because my JQuery sucks....
Can anybody help me out with some JQuery fix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `animateTransform` methods for vertical scale to transform a circle to a line and for translate-Y to hold transformation origin in the center of circle

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 95.28 95.28">
  <title>circle</title>
  <g>
  <circle cx="47.64" cy="47.64" r="47.14" fill="none" stroke="#1d1d1b" stroke-miterlimit="10">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    from="1 1"
    to="1 0"
    begin="0s"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
  </circle>
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    from="0 0"
    to="0 24"
    begin="0s"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh wow this is awesome. I'll read up on `<animateTransform>`. Didn't know about that one. Thnx mate.

Comment: be aware that animateTransform is depricated and will be removed from browsers. this solution is not future prove :-(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965580/deprecated-smil-svg-animation-replaced-with-css-or-web-animations-effects-hover

Comment: Thnx. That sucks. So here's a no go

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in life you shouldn't overthink everything.
The answer was really simple but I just thought to hard.

A simple `scale()` did the trick.

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} 
 
@keyframes shapeshifter {
 0% {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 }  
 100% {
  transform: scale(1,0.01);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 } 
}
.shape{ 
 animation: shapeshifter 1s ease-in-out 1 both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <title>circle</title>
  <circle class="shape" cx="50.109" cy="50.086" r="47.14" fill="none" stroke="#1d1d1b" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
</div>
```