# SMIL SVG animation works in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: animation, svg, smil

This is an animation I built using `smil` animation elements.

Intended animation:

1. Droplet fades in: `<animate> element`,
2. then drops: `<animateTransform> element`.
3. Fades out before completing translate on y axis.

This works in Firefox.

In Chrome (Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit))
this animation does not show the fade effects from the `<animate> element` - timeline is defined by the `keyTimes` and `values` attributes.

However it does work when defined by the `keyFrames` attribute, which I don' think is actually an attribute.  I learned this works via typo.

The `keyTimes` attribute does work on the `<animateTransform> element` for the translate motion in Chrome.

So I have spent all of 2-3 days learning about smil animation, and maybe I am missing something here.

Any thoughts?

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/robleroy/pen/rNeygVM)

Comment: Remove the spurious ; at the end of the keyTimes and values attributes.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965580/deprecated-smil-svg-animation-replaced-with-css-or-web-animations-effects-hover) about SMIL being deprecated in Chrome may give some insight?

Comment: Thanks @Robert Longson..  That was it!

Comment: @Jan Stránský - yes I had read about the deprecation, and the suspension of that deprecation.  Thank you for your input.